# Using PGP to verify GDB in an Alpine container

Tags: docker, gdb, gnu, gnupg, alpine-linux

I have compiled information from GNU.org, blogs and other SO posts, but I am missing a key component to properly validate the version of GDB I'm downloading into my container.

```
# Install GNU GDB
RUN ["/bin/ash","-c","\
    mkdir gdb-build \
 && cd gdb-build \
 && wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-8.1.tar.xz \
 && wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-8.1.tar.xz.sig \
 && gpg --import https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-keyring.gpg \
 && gpg --verify --keyring ./gnu-keyring.gpg gdb-8.1.tar.xz.sig \
 && tar -xvf gdb-8.1.tar.xz \
 && cd gdb-8.1 \
 && ./configure --prefix=/usr \
 && make \
 && make -C gdb install \
 && cd .. \
 && rm -rf gdb-build/ \
"]
```

The output looks like this:

```
...
2018-03-10 18:04:52 (5.92 MB/s) - 'gdb-8.1.tar.xz' saved [20095080/20095080]

--2018-03-10 18:04:52--  https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-8.1.tar.xz.sig
Resolving ftp.gnu.org... 208.118.235.20, 2001:4830:134:3::b
Connecting to ftp.gnu.org|208.118.235.20|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 72 [application/pgp-signature]
Saving to: 'gdb-8.1.tar.xz.sig'

     0K                                                       100% 1.27M=0s

2018-03-10 18:04:52 (1.27 MB/s) - 'gdb-8.1.tar.xz.sig' saved [72/72]

gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: can't open 'https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-keyring.gpg': No such file or directory
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

What step am I missing? How do appropriately configure GnuPG to access the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax of `gpg` command is:

```
Syntax: gpg [options] [files]
Sign, check, encrypt or decrypt
Default operation depends on the input data
```

A command `gpg --import` requires file, not a link, so `gnu-keyring.gpg` should be downloaded before the `gpg` command.

The correct part of `Dockerfile` is:

```
RUN ["/bin/ash","-c","\
    mkdir gdb-build \
 && cd gdb-build \
 && wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-8.1.tar.xz \
 && wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-8.1.tar.xz.sig \
 && wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-keyring.gpg \
 && gpg --import ./gnu-keyring.gpg \
 && gpg --verify --keyring ./gnu-keyring.gpg gdb-8.1.tar.xz.sig \
 && tar -xvf gdb-8.1.tar.xz \
 && cd gdb-8.1 \
 && ./configure --prefix=/usr \
 && make \
 && make -C gdb install \
 && cd .. \
 && rm -rf gdb-build/ \
"]
```